# How to count cells that contain word in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, countif, google-sheets-formula

I have in Google sheet plenty of columns and I have about 15,000 rows, I want to count how many cells contain "NA" these 2 letters in column F.

Comment: For example: `=SUMPRODUCT(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Searchvalue",A1:Z15000)))` or a simple `=COUNTIF(A1:Z15000,"*Searchvalue*")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try simple `COUNTIF` like:

```
=COUNTIF(F:F, "NA")
```

[image: 0]